# Store user's input in a asp.net web page?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a web page that reads xml files to display server statistics. Ideally i want the users to be able to setup and save multiple connections to different servers. They would then be able to choose which server they wish to view through a asp.net web page.

What would be the best way to store the details of the connections to the servers the users have defined?

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of server-side storage, like a database, or a file if a database is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go for a file since it is faster than a database

Comment: LIke an xml file? Where would i save it to though? Locally to the machine the user is using to view the statistics?

Comment: Should I save it locally to the machine then? Or to the server?